# How can I install a script into blender?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, scripting, installation

[image]

I want to install this extension to my blender to get materials to save from blender render to cycles render. Anyways when I clicked on the installation link this is what appeared(picture). How do I use this to install the script to blender?

Comment: just to clarify, there's only a few ways to install an addon and they apply to all addons. So the question is unique, but the answer can be found in the linked answer.